Expo React Native error 'translations' does not exist on type 'typeof import("c:/xampp/htdocs/.../node_modules/i18n-js/typings/index")'
I am trying to implement translations into my React Native Expo app. It installed these libraries:
npx expo install i18next react-i18next expo-localization

I am running:
import i18n from 'i18n-js';
import { en, lt } from './../../localizations';

i18n.translations = {en, lt};

And it seem that i18n doesnt have such property as translations (even though all tutorials suggest to do it like this). What can be the problem and how to solve it/what else to use?
